# Multiple encryption append to a file

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, rncryptor

I have a log of a programs state. This log can be manualy or time interval saved on a file for persistant storage. Before saving it to the file it is encrypted with [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor).

My current appending(saving) to file flow:

1. Read file
2. Decript information from the read string
3. Concat decrypted string with the new string
4. Encrypt the concatenated string
5. Write it to file

What I imagine:

1. Encode new string
2. Append to file

When I read this I will have to build a string from all the encoded strings. But I don't know how to decrypt the file with multiple encrypted blocks in it. How to differentiate where one ends and another begins.
Also is this the best performance choice. The text in the file at maximum could get to 100MB(Possibly it will never get this big).
Is using [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreData_ObjC/) viable? Each append as different record or something. And core data could be encrypted so no need for [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor).

Would appreciate code in Objective-C if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things you can do:

- Easiest would be to encode the ciphertexts to text (e.g. with Base64) and write each encoded ciphertext to a new line. You need encoding for that, because the ciphertext itself might contain bytes that can be interpreted as newline control characters, but that won't happen with a text encoding. The problem with this is that it blows up the logs unnecessarily (e.g. by 33% if Base64 is used)
- You can prepend each unencoded ciphertext with its length (e.g. big-endian int32 encoding) and write both as-is to a file in binary mode. If you begin reading the file from the beginning, then you can distinguish each ciphertext, because you know how long the following ciphertext is and when the next encoded length starts. The blowup is only as big as the encoding of the ciphertext length for each ciphertext.
- Use a binary delimiter such as 0x0101 between ciphertexts, but such a delimiter might still appear in the ciphertexts, so you need to escape it if you find it somewhere in the ciphertext. This is a little tricky to get right.
- If the amount of logs is small (few MB), then you can find a library to append to a ZIP file.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I think I will either go with your second or your last point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array to store the information and then read and write that array to file. find [Example here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/read-and-write-nsarray-nsdictionary-and-nsset-to-a-file.html).

Steps :

1. Read Array from the file.
2. Add the New Encrypted string to array.
3. Write array to file.

Comment: This is a little better as it skips decryption every time, but it still has to read the whole array from the file in order to append to it and then save the newly created array.